# https redirection with dnsmasq

Tags: https, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq

I am using a raspberry pi for my project and also I have setup my pi as a wifi access point.
I am trying to create a landing page to which all the http and https requests must be redirected when a user is connected to pi's  wifi access point.
I am using dnsmasq right now for redirection,with which the http redirection is working perfectly.
But I am not able to figure out how to redirect https requests with dnsmasq.

I used the "address=/#/192.168.137.45"  option to enable http redirection.
Can I use the same for https or if not possible help me with some other possibilities.

How about using iptables? Is it a part of dnsmasq or different from it?

Comment: all other details available on request

Answer (score 0):

In order to inspect HTTPS, you need install for example SQUID and enable SSL Inspection.